# Cython without Console on Windows

Tags: python, windows, console, cython, mingw32

I have compiled my program, he works. But i use tkinter and i want compile this program.

My commands :

```
cython.exe --embed file.py -o file.c

gcc.exe file.c -o file -I C:/Python27/include -L C:/Python/libs -lpython27
```

I use cygwin and mingw32, and i am on windows.

My program works but i have windows console with, and i don't want that console.

My research find that pythonw.exe don't launch console, and i think py2exe use that, but i want one file, i use cython for that.

Can i launch pythonw.exe with cython and not python.exe ?
Or better, can i disable console ?
How ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add `-Wl,--subsystem,windows` to your gcc commandline on your link step.  In your case:

```
gcc -o file file.c -I c:/Python27/include -L c:/Python27/libs -lpython27 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

This will pass along `--subsystem windows` to the linker, which will produce an executable which runs without a console window.

Comment: Thans for you response, he works !

But i have two problems now...

On an other computer, he want python27.dll, but i'm created libpython27.a etc... How ? And, when i have installed python27.dll, he didn't work, nothing error message, nothing program...

Comment: If you are trying to deploy to another machine, that does get tricky to track down all the dependencies.  I'd start by copying your version of c:\windows\system32\python27.dll (you might find it in c:\windows\syswow64\python27.dll) and put it in the same folder as your .exe.  Also, copy everything from c:\python27\DLLs\ and put those files in the same folder.  (NOT in a DLLs subfolder.)  Do the same for c:\python27\lib\ (again, in the same folder, not in a subfolder.)

Comment: Can i compile all this file in my exe for one standalone program ? With which command ? Can you give me the gcc command please ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it raises a fatal error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)`

Comment: Never mind, I messed around with the generated file renaming methods until I got it to work, thank you so much you're a life saver!!!