# cython --embed with no console window

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, cython, cl.exe

*(Linked to [Cython without Console on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314557/cython-without-console-on-windows) but this  one is for Python 2.7 and mingw, the solutions don't work directly here)*

This allows to create a .exe with Cython:

```
cython test.py --embed
call vcvarsall.bat x64
cl test.c /I C:\Python38\include /link C:\Python38\libs\python38.lib
```

It works, and then `test.exe` starts the program in a terminal console window.

**How to compile with `cython --embed` it without a console window?**

I tried

```
cl test.c /I C:\Python38\include /link C:\Python38\libs\python38.lib /subsystem:window
```

but it fails with:

> LIBCMT.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)

Comment: you probably need to add `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`  but I cannot test it now (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934206/what-is-the-difference-between-main-and-maincrtstartup)

Comment: Thanks @ead. I tried `cl test.c /I C:\Python38\include /link C:\Python38\libs\python38.lib /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup /subsystem:windows` but I still have `LIBCMT.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)" (?__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython produces usually `wmain` instead of `main` so you could use widechar as command line argument when calling the resulting executable.

Thus you need to tell the linker to look for `wmain` this is done via option:

```
/ENTRY:wmainCRTStartup
```

which differently as `mainCRTStartup` will look for `wmain`.

It is important to use `/ENTRY:wmainCRTStartup` and not just `/ENTRY:wmain` because otherwise the code, which should run before `wmain` is called (e.g. initialization of static variables) won't run.

The full solution is then:

```
cl test.c /I C:\Python38\include /link C:\Python38\libs\python38.lib /subsystem:windows /ENTRY:wmainCRTStartup
```